# monitor and permit or disallow internet traffic

Tags: networking, internet, system-monitor

I've seen something similar to the following:
When a program requests a resource from the internet, I get an alert of the contents of this , and whether to allow or disallow it ..

I could see the contents in understandable way like communication to URL XXX using GET request with payload....

What kind of software can do this? Wireshark? (if yes, i think its overkill for this task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TuxGuardian, Leopard Flower, and Program Guard are linux programs that will prompt a user when any program tries to access the network, thus allowing the user to choose allow or don't allow. Unforunately these are all small projects, so they aren't distro specific which makes installation very hard.

pgrd.sourceforge.net/

tuxguardian.sourceforge.net/

leopardflower.sourceforge.net/

Comment: But How can I see the content of payload before allowing or disallowing ? and what do you mean by very hard, please?

Comment: These programs unfortunately don't list where the request is headed or even what protocol is being used, only which program has made the request. As far as difficult to install I mean that they aren't in the repos so they take some work to get running. Checkout the install instructions for Leopard Flower for example: http://sourceforge.net/projects/leopardflower/files/